# How to Populate a jeasyui DataGrid with Spring Controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I'm not achieving to mimetize [this tutorial](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php) using Spring MVC controller.

DataGrid is not populating its rows with Java/Spring Controller data retrieved. I'm not reproducing my entyre JSP which code is quite similar to that from example above.

The Spring "ControlTeste" as follows is responsible for retrieving data from DB, build a Json string (using Gson) and sending it as response. In the tutorial, this task is done with PHP (directly from view, without a "controller" layer).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ControlTeste", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String teste(Status Status, HttpSession httpSession) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Session sess = (Session) httpSession.getAttribute("hibSess");
        StatusDAO staDao = new StatusDAO(sess);
        List<Status> lista = staDao.findAll();
        String gStatus = new String();
        try{
            gStatus = gson.toJson(lista);
            System.out.println(gStatus);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return gStatus;
    }
```

The Json generated is:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "descricao": "Novo Status",
    "sigla": "STA",
    "estadoFinal": true,
    "erro": true
  }
```

And DataGrid's Config (in JSP) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dg').edatagrid({  
    url: 'ControlTeste',  
    saveUrl: 'StatusCreate',  
    updateUrl: 'StatusUpdate',  
    destroyUrl: 'StatusDelete'  
});  

<table id="dg" title="Cadastro de Status" class="easyui-datagrid"
    style="width: 700px; height: 250px" url="ControlTeste"
    toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true" rownumbers="true"
    fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="id" width="20">ID</th>
            <th field="sigla" width="40">Sigla</th>
            <th field="descricao" width="50">Descrição</th>
            <th field="erro" width="30">Erro?</th>
            <th field="estadoFinal" width="30">Estado Final?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="toolbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"
        iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="novo()">Novo</a> <a
        href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"
        iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editar()">Editar</a> <a
        href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"
        iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="remover()">Remover</a>
</div>
```

Right now I'm interested only in "ControlTeste" controller, due to it is responsible for retrieving data to populate the DataGrid.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to my question, probably it would be usefull to sb someday:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/StatusLista")
    public @ResponseBody String teste(Status Status, 
                                        HttpSession httpSession, 
                                        HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        Session sess = (Session) httpSession.getAttribute("hibSess");
        StatusDAO staDao = new StatusDAO(sess);
        List<Status> lista = staDao.findAll();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String gListStatus = gson.toJson(lista);
        return gListStatus;
    }
```

I've just done some changings in my Controller method (and I've changed its name too).